# How to install Docker on Sagemaker Terminal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I've created an account on Amazon AWS, and want to use the Sagemaker to utilize GPUs since my local machine is too weak for machine learning algos. I locally created a Docker image and pushed it onto Docker Hub. Now I want to pull this image into the Sagemaker, run the image and execute some machine learning code which I placed within the image.

I logged into Sagemaker, launched a Terminal, and tried to install Docker:

`sudo yum install docker`

but this gives `No package docker available.`

`sudo yum search docker`

finds only `pcp-pmda-docker.x86_64`:

```
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
================================================================================ N/S matched: docker ================================================================================
pcp-pmda-docker.x86_64 : Performance Co-Pilot (PCP) metrics from the Docker daemon
nerdctl.x86_64 : nerdctl is a Docker-compatible CLI for containerd.

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

The OS seems to be "Amazon Linux" (`cat /etc/os-release`):

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
```

How do I install Docker on Sagemaker Terminal?

Comment: Heeey, have you found an answer to this yet?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recall fully what I did... but I remember I abandoned Sagemaker altogether as it was too limiting, and rented a regular EC2 instance where I chose a machine with 4 GPUs and with preinstalled Linux distribution I needed.